# How to save the original grayscale image data stored in an array as a picture in Java?

Tags: bufferedimage

I can obtain the size and original data of the grayscale image through the API, but I have not found a suitable method to store these data as pictures.

I tried using BufferedImage to handle it but don't know how to transfer the contents stored with the array into BufferedImage.

```
byte[] buffer = API.readGrayScaleImageRawData();
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, length, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

//TODO: how to transfer the content from buffer to bufferedImage
```

Comment: What is "buffer"? You can iterate over the pixels and call setRGB for each pixel. Another way is to create a raster from buffer and set the raster in one go.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705385/how-to-convert-a-byte-to-a-bufferedimage-in-java There are different types of answers depending on what is in your byte[]. If each byte is a grayscale value then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29428561/2067492) is probably the most efficient.

Comment: Try the options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54254056/1428606). Both should work for you, if `buffer` contains grayscale "raw" pixel data.